# VMWare Fusion Multiple Display Issue

Tags: vmware-fusion

I have VMWare Fusion (8.5.7) running on an Macbook host (10.12.6).  The guest machine is Windows 10.  If the guest has been run while the Macbook is not connected to external monitors, then it becomes virtually impossible to get it to work right after monitors are connected.

Instead, I get the same desktop mirrored onto all monitors instead of an "extended" desktop.  Restarting the guest does not fix the problem.  I have tried a lot of things, such as switching to a single window and back to full screen.  Windows cannot see the external monitors.

About the only fix I have discovered is to shut down the guest, restart the Macbook, then start up the guest.  After this it works as desired.  But if the Macbook is disconnected from the monitors, then reconnected to the monitors, all bets are off.  I have to shut down the guest AND the host again to get the extended desktop to work.

***Has anyone else experienced this problem and found a solution?***

Here is a photo of the undesirable and seemingly unfixable state.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried hitting Detect?

Comment: Yes I have.  Nothing happens.

Comment: There is a good chance the problem is with VMware Fusion itself.  I assume you are running Windows 10 1703?

Comment: I'm not sure how to check the Windows build.  It is Windows 10 Pro, up-to-date.

Comment: You can run 'winver' but how you determine what build your running a well documented subject

Comment: This problem has persisted through many Windows 10 updates and now persists with High Sierra on the host. I would buy VMWare Fusion 10 happily if it were known to fix this issue.

Comment: After nearly three months you still have provided the information I requested

Comment: Version 1703 (OS Build 15063.674).